# Multiple setTimeout's

Tags: javascript

There seems to be a conflict between my two timers, I want to know how to make them totally independent but executing on the same page.. Here is the code:

WHEN THE PAGE LOADS

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
     setTimeout("AlterTwitterTimer();", 60000);
     setTimeout("MainStatusTimer();", 60000);
}
</script>
```

OTHER RELATED SCRIPTS

```
function AlterTwitterTimer()
{
     document.getElementById('TwitterTimer').innerHTML = '0';
}

function MainStatusTimer()
{
     document.getElementById('MainStatusTimer').innerHTML = '0';
}

function DelayedRefresh(DashCity)
{
     if(document.getElementById('TwitterTimer').innerHTML == '0')
     {
          document.getElementById('fmeProcess').src = '/ajax/twitter_feed_ajax.asp?id='NY';
          document.getElementById('TwitterTimer').innerHTML = '1';
          setTimeout("AlterTwitterTimer();", 60000);
     }
}

function DelayedStatusRefresh()
{
     if(document.getElementById('MainStatusTimer').innerHTML == '0')
     {
          document.getElementById('fmeProcess').src = '/ajax/dash_board_status.asp';
          document.getElementById('MainStatusTimer').innerHTML = '1';
          setTimeout("MainStatusTimer();", 60000);
     }
}
```

Any help you can provide would be great appreciated.

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:

```
setTimeout(AlterTwitterTimer, 60000);
setTimeout(MainStatusTimer, 60000);
```

Second, they *are* unrelated. Each `setTimeout` call returns a numeric ID that you can later pass to `clearTimeout` to cancel the delayed call.